# Explicit type is missing

Tags: c++

I am developing a group chat application. I am getting explicit type missing, 'int' assumed error in the below mentioned line.

```
static _Atomic unsigned int cli_count = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`_Atomic` is a keyword in C. It is not part of C++.

The C++ equivalent is (assuming C++17 or later here)

```
#include<atomic>

//...

static std::atomic<unsigned int> cli_count = 0;
```